# WebView transparency does not work when hardware acceleration is turend on

Tags: android, webview, transparency, hardware-acceleration

When using Android 3.0+ and enabling hardware acceleration in your AndroidManifest.xml file, WebViews can no longer be transparent. Even worse, transparent parts of images in your web content are just rendered white!

So the question is, is there a workaround or are we forced to live without hardware acceleration (or transparency in webviews)?

Comment: This is fixed in Android 4.1.1.

Comment: It is also fine in Android 4.2.2. Any idea exactly what version the fix was in?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently broken in 3.0+ with hardware acceleration turned on.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14749